# Ajax with jQuery, submit handler

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I still need your help. Today, I would like to develop a small feature in Ajax with jQuery.

I found a simple tutorial, which answers my wish. Author uses Jquery Validate Plugin, I do not need.

I don't know how to translate the code without the use this plugin. I tried dozens of combinations (I'm not very gifted!).

Here is original code...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myform").validate({
        debug: false,
        rules: {
        ///
        },
        messages: {
        ///
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) { // How to repace this?
            $.post('process.php', $("#myform").serialize(), function(data) {
                $('#results').html(data);
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Thanks for your help. :)

Regards,

Vincent

Answer (score 6):

Check out [`.submit()`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myform").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // This part stays the same
        $.post('process.php', $("#myform").serialize(), function(data) {
            $('#results').html(data);
        });
    });
});
```

... Which binds an *event handler* to the *submit event* of your form. `e.preventDefault` then prevents the form from being submitted normally (without ajax).

Comment: Yes, it works and I prefer your solution. Thanks to you and to others. (I read Api before my ask. ^^)

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = $("#myForm").serialize();
$.ajax
                            ({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "mail.php",
                            data: data,
                            cache: false,
                            success: function()
                                {
                                    alert("Thank you");
                                }
                            });
```

This is the basic premise for AJAX with jQuery - you should be able to sub in your code with this easily :)

Answer (score 0):

Well,

what about just sending your data to the server and waiting for the answer?

```
$.ajax({
   url: '/your_script_url',
   data: ({data_1 : "data_1", data_n : "data_n"}),
   success: function(data) { do something; } } );
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Please always navigate here for more info

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/